TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') Invalid hook call
I’m currently working on integrating Storybook into my TurboRepo setup, which contains two Next.js projects. I’m implementing Storybook in the first project, but I’m encountering an "Invalid hook call" error.
Setup Details:
TurboRepo Structure: The repository consists of two Next.js applications and a shared components package.
First Project: This is where I’m trying to set up Storybook.
Second Project: This project consumes the shared components.
Third Project: This is the shared components package.
I’ve included the relevant package.json files for each project below:
First Project (Storybook Next App):
{
  "name": "storybook-next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.14",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "1.9.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/blocks": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/react": "8.3.4",
    "@storybook/test": "8.3.4",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.14",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.9.0",
    "storybook": "8.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


Second Project (Web):
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@repo/shared-components": "workspace:*",
    "next": "14.2.14",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repo/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.0-rc.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "typescript": "^5"
  },
  "name": "web",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0"
}


root package.json
{
  "name": "payroll-ui-2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo build",
    "start": "pnpm install && turbo run start",
    "dev": "turbo dev",
    "lint": "turbo lint",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.3.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.2.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.4.2",
    "@types/react-image-gallery": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.7",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "turbo": "latest",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "packageManager": "pnpm@8.15.6",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.20",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.20",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "6.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.6.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.8.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.48.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.48.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^31.3.2",
    "ag-grid-react": "^31.3.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "1.0.4-alpha.1",
    "file64": "1.0.1",
    "i18next": "^23.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "next": "14.2.14",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.5",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.2",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "react-webcam": "7.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "usehooks-ts": "^3.1.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  }
}


While running Storybook, I get the following error message:
chunk-EPPXVIAF.mjs:18 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

react.development.js:2516 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
at Object.useRef (react.development.js:2516:1)
at WithCallback (react-18.mjs:4:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:11121:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:16869:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18458:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:20565:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:20614:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:20689:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26949:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25748:1)
What I Tried:

Separate Execution: I ran "app 1" outside the TurboRepo setup, and it executed without any issues, confirming that the Storybook setup works independently.

Dependency Check: I reviewed the package.json files across all projects to ensure that the versions of react and react-dom are consistent (all set to ^18).

Import Paths: I verified the import paths in the shared components to ensure they are correct.

Peer Dependencies: I considered adding react and react-dom as peer dependencies in the shared components package to enforce a single version across the monorepo.

Minimal Setup: I attempted to create a minimal version of the TurboRepo setup, including only the necessary projects and shared components, to see if the issue persists.

Documentation Review: React documentation on hook rules and the Storybook documentation for setup guidelines.


I was expecting to integrate Storybook into "app 1" without encountering the "Invalid hook call" error. Specifically, I hoped to seamlessly use shared components without facing issues related to multiple React instances or hook violations.
